# View is not updating when the button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, uibutton

The problem is that when the button is clicked, it is not updating! it is not hiding or showing the objects like it's written in the code. What am I missing?

viewcontroller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    BOOL clicked1;
    BOOL clicked2;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *buttonbg1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *buttonbg11;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *buttonbg111;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *exaa1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *exab2;

- (IBAction)exaa1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)exab2:(id)sender;

@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)exaa1:(id)sender {
    clicked1 = YES;
}

- (IBAction)exab2:(id)sender {
    clicked2 = YES;
}

- (void)example1 {
    [_exaa1 setTitle:@"1111" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_exab2 setTitle:@"2222" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if (clicked1) {
        _buttonbg111.hidden = NO;
        _buttonbg11.hidden = YES;
        _buttonbg1.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"1");

    } else if(clicked2) {
        _buttonbg11.hidden = NO;
        _buttonbg1.hidden = YES;
        _buttonbg111.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not calling the "example1" method. Add `[self example1];` to your IBAction.

Answer (score 0):

```
*- (IBAction)exaa1:(id)sender {
    clicked1 = YES;
    [self example1];
}
- (IBAction)exab2:(id)sender {
    clicked2 = YES;
    [self example1];
}
- (void)example1 {
    [_exaa1 setTitle:@"1111" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_exab2 setTitle:@"2222" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if (clicked1) {
        _buttonbg111.hidden = NO;
        _buttonbg11.hidden = YES;
        _buttonbg1.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"1");
    } else if(clicked2) {
        _buttonbg11.hidden = NO;
        _buttonbg1.hidden = YES;
        _buttonbg111.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
}*
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forget to call your method example1 in your both IBActions Method. YOu just write down [self example1] into both of the IBActions method. And you will get your exact output.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to call `example1` method  in both button IBAction methods

Answer (score 0):

```
Please refer the following corrected code   
 - (IBAction)exaa1:(id)sender {
        clicked1 = YES;
        clicked2 = NO;
        [self example1];
    }

    - (IBAction)exab2:(id)sender {
        clicked2 = YES;
        clicked1 = NO;
        [self example1];
    }

    - (void)example1 {
        [_exaa1 setTitle:@"1111" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_exab2 setTitle:@"2222" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        if (clicked1) {
            _buttonbg111.hidden = NO;
            _buttonbg11.hidden = YES;
            _buttonbg1.hidden = YES;
            NSLog(@"1");

        } else if(clicked2) {
            _buttonbg11.hidden = NO;
            _buttonbg1.hidden = YES;
            _buttonbg111.hidden = YES;
            NSLog(@"2");
        }
    }
```